Error: src/app/config/config.ts:5:41 - error TS2339: Property 'URL_FRONTEND' does not exist on type '{}'
Buen dia,
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Angular, Laravel, MySQL, JWT, etc. El proyecto es bastante extenso y he llegado a una parte de este donde no he podido avanzar por el siguiente error.

He probado de todo para solucionarlo y no lo he conseguido, agradeceria de su ayuda. Es un proyecto bastante importante. Dejo capturas de los archivos.
Environment.ts

config.ts

auth.service.ts

Todos los archivos estan dentro de la misma carpeta, se me olvido comentar.
Agradeceria mucho de su ayuda.
Gracias.

Código como texto, si pones capturas de pantalla es poco probable que te ayuden.

Revisa si tienes dos archivos environment y fíjate cuál estás importando.
